# Vue Bootstrap 4 Navbar Height & Dropdown Not Working On Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am having the following issue with my Navbar on Safari browsers:

[image]

I do not own an iOS device or Mac so I can not debug it locally. I've already tried adding an empty `href="#"` to my `b-navbar-toggle` as recommended by another thread without any luck.

My navbar code looks as follows. There is no additional CSS added.

```
 <template>
  <b-navbar id="nav" toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="dark">
    <b-container>
      <b-navbar-brand to="/">TRIAB</b-navbar-brand>
      <b-navbar-toggle href="#" target="nav-text-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
      <b-collapse href="#" id="nav-text-collapse" is-nav>
        <b-navbar-nav>
          <b-nav-item active-class="active" exact to="/">{{ $t('nav.home') }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item active-class="active" to="/about">{{ $t('nav.about') }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item active-class="active" to="/products">{{ $t('nav.products') }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item active-class="active" to="/news">{{ $t('nav.news') }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item active-class="active" to="/contact">{{ $t('nav.contact') }}</b-nav-item>
        </b-navbar-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
          <b-nav-item @click="$i18n.locale = 'en'">
            <img src="../../assets/img/flags/us.png" alt="us flag">
          </b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item @click="$i18n.locale = 'sv'">
            <img src="../../assets/img/flags/sv.png" alt="sv flag">
          </b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-container>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

The navbar works without issue on both Android, Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `display: flex;` to `display: webkit-box;` fixed the issue on Safari and iOS devices.